# Unity field containing ScriptableObject not serializing

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem getting a field to serialize properly.

It links to a custom type which extends `ScriptableObject`. A custom editor is creating the instance of this object, and it's not being saved as an asset file. It's my understanding at the moment that you can do this - Unity should be saving this data into the scene instead of the project automatically.

First up, the `MonoBehaviour` class. This I've set up to hold an instance of Bar and a string just to double check the serialization is working at all. I use fields with exposing properties, so I've done it here as well as I know reflection is involved.

```
public class Foo : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Bar bar;

    [SerializeField]
    private string check;

    public Bar Bar { get { return this.bar; } set { this.bar = value; } }
}
```

Next, the `ScriptableObject` based `Bar` class. This is the class I want to instance and link, but not save as an asset file.

```
[Serializable]
public class Bar : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField]
    private string data;
}
```

Finally, a `CustomEditor` which allows me to create and link an instance of `Bar`:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Foo))]
public class StreamableResourceTestEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        if (GUILayout.Button("Link unsaved Bar asset"))
        {
            Bar bar = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Bar>();
            bar.name = "Unsaved asset";

            Foo foo = (Foo)this.target;
            foo.Bar = bar;

            EditorUtility.SetDirty(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Before running, having entered data and pressed the button:

[image: Before Running]

During running:

[image]

After running:

[image]

---

The string serializes properly.

However, the `ScriptableObject` fails to be serialized into the runtime data. Not only that, after running the project the instance is still linked, but has lost it's type!

Does anyone know what the problem is with this?

---

**Update:**

Just tested this without extending `Bar` from `ScriptableObject`, and creating it as a normal C# instance instead of with `ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Bar>` and it all works as expected.

Whatever the problem is, it relates to extending from ScriptableObject.

Comment: Unrelated but your property is named the same as the type. I would give it a different naming as it could conflict.

Comment: What with all the reflection in the Unity serializer, certainly worth a check - changed it over to MyBar, same results though sadly.